Pick nested fields in TypeScript while maintaining optionality/nullability
My question is quite similar to this one, but mine is a bit trickier because I'd like to keep null and optional fields as they are.
Let's say I have a GraphQL query for a shipping page that looks like this:
query getShippingData() {
  myData {
    address {
      country {
        twoDigitsCode
      }
    }
  }
}

And I have a generated file of all possible interfaces that my GraphQL endpoint produces:
interface GQLUserData {
  id: string;
  email?: null | string;
  address?: null | GQLUserAddress;
}

interface GQLUserAddress {
  street: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country?: null | GQLCountry;
}

interface GQLCountry {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  available: boolean;
  twoDigitsCode?: null | string;
}

But I can't just import and use the whole GQLCountry for example, because it contains several other properties that I didn't ask for in my query.
How can I use the generated file of types in my favor to accomplish the interface below?
interface ShippingDataResponse {
  myData: {
    address?: null | {
      country?: null | {
        twoDigitsCode?: null | string;
      }
    }
  }
}

The similar question I linked solves it by using the Pick type-utility and re-declaring the picked field and a nested picked interface.
interface ShippingDataResponse {
  myData: {
    address: {
      country: Pick<GQLCountry, 'twoDigitsCode'>;
    }
  }
}

While this may look like it does exactly what I want, this is actually re-declaring address and country as non-optional and non-nullable fields, and it would result in a wrong interface, like so:
interface ShippingDataResponse {
  myData: {
    address: {
      country: {
        twoDigitsCode?: null | string;
      }
    }
  }
}

This completely removes the nullability/optionality from address and country.
To solve this I would have to go into the generated file of types, and look what fields are optional or nullable and manually mark them as so.
That just invalidates the whole point of having this generated file of types in the first place, since it is a 4K LOC file and may change without any prior notice.
I need my types to be always in-sync with the produced values from the GraphQL.

Type libraries will help you for that: DeepNullable and DeepPartial in ts-essentials, Nullable and Optional in ts-toolbelt, …

thanks @Blackhole ts-essentials DeepPick solved it flawlessly


DeepPick<Type, Filter> from ts-essentials constructs a type by picking set of properties, which have property values true in type Filter, from type Type.

The usage is like so:
import { DeepPick } from 'ts-essentials';

type InitialShippingResponse = DeepPick<
  { myData: GQLUserData },
  {
    myData: {
      address: {
        country: {
          twoDigitsCode: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
>;



The problem is that when you use the Pick utility like this type MyType = Pick<GQLCountry, 'twoDigitsCode'>
It creates a new type that only includes the twoDigitsCode property. However, this new type doesn’t carry over the fact that twoDigitsCode might be null or undefined. It simply takes the type as defined for that property (string | null) but doesn’t know anything about the context in which it was optional (?).
Solution
To maintain the optionality and nullability while picking only the fields you need, you need a custom utility type that works recursively, ensuring that nested properties are correctly preserved as optional and/or nullable.
type CustomPick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P] extends object
  ? CustomPick<T[P], keyof T[P]>
  : T[P];
};

Now you can use like this:
type CustomType = CustomPick<GQLCountry, 'twoDigitsCode'>` 

And this will be the same as
type CustomType = {
  twoDigitsCode?: string | null | undefined;
}

This is a breakdown of the utility type just in case someone wants a deeper explanation
1. T and K extends keyof T

T: This is the type from which you want to pick properties. It could be any object type, like an interface or a complex type with nested properties.
K extends keyof T: This part defines K as a subset of the keys of T. The keyof T expression returns a union of all keys (property names) in T. By saying K extends keyof T, you’re indicating that K can only be one or more of those keys.

2. [P in K]:
This part uses TypeScript’s mapped types syntax.

[P in K]: This iterates over each key P in the union K. Essentially, for each key in K, it creates a property in the resulting type. This is the core mechanism that lets you “pick” properties from the type T.

3. T[P] extends object
This is a conditional type check.

T[P]: This represents the type of the property P in T. For example, if T is { name: string; age: number } and P is "name", then T[P] is string.
extends object: This checks whether the type T[P] is an object (or something that behaves like an object, such as another interface or a complex type). The purpose of this check is to determine whether the property P itself might contain nested properties that need to be recursively picked.

4. ? CustomPick<T[P], keyof T[P]> : T[P]
This is the ternary operator that decides what the resulting type will be based on the condition.

If T[P] is an object: If the type of P is an object, the type will recursively apply CustomPick to this object. This means it will take T[P], find its keys using keyof T[P], and apply CustomPick to pick those keys. This ensures that the nested structure is preserved and correctly narrowed down to the fields you need.
If T[P] is not an object: If the type of P is not an object (e.g., it’s a primitive type like string, number, boolean, etc.), then the type is simply T[P]. This means it picks the value type as is without any further processing.

